# QGIS Spatial Query Providers Issue

Tags: qgis, spatial-query

During the tutorial : http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/performing_spatial_queries.html

I have a error message like below.

[[image: [1]]

What is the **providers** mean?

I really try to figure it out but nothing I can find.

My qgis version is QGIS 2.18.19